# Integral of a derivative vs derivative of an integral?

Tags: calculus

I'm learning the fundamental theorem of calculus, and was confused on something. Is the original function $f(x)$ equal to the integral of the derivative, i.e. $\int f'(x)\ dx$, or equal to the derivative of the integral, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx} \int f(x)\ dx $?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: derivative of an integral.

The [first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) and [second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) parts of the FTC respectively specify sufficient conditions, which we'll assume hereafter are correct, to obtain$$\tfrac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)dt=f(x),\,\int_a^bF^\prime(t)=F(b)-F(a).$$So the first part recovers $f$ as the derivative of a definite integral $F(x):=\int_a^xf(t)dt$, while the second part recovers $F$ as a definite integral of the derivative $f:=F^\prime$

Note that if you differentiate an integral by the first part you get the original function, but if you integrate the derivative by the second part you get an arbitrary antiderivative, i.e. recover the original function up to an additive constant. (This "constant" is more generally a *locally constant function*, e.g. antiderivatives of $1/x$ can differ by different amounts either side of $x=0$.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, now I got it.